# In tkinter, button moves down from its previous position when label text appear on window

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

When the button "Calculate BMI" is pressed the value appear above button as expected but pushes the button down. **I want to fix the button whether pressed or not.**

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("ASA Downloader")
window.geometry("400x400")
frame1 = LabelFrame(window, padx=100, pady=100)

#Labels
weight_label = Label(frame1, text= "Weight")
height_label = Label(frame1, text= "Height")

weight_label.grid(row=0,column=0, columnspan=3)
height_label.grid(row=1,column=0, columnspan=3)

#Entery of weight
int_type= IntVar
w_entry= Entry(frame1, textvariable= int_type)
w_entry.grid(row=0, column=3, columnspan=2)

#Entery of height
h_entry= Entry(frame1, textvariable= int_type)
h_entry.grid(row=1, column=3, columnspan=2)


def bmi():

    result_lable= Label(frame1, text=w_entry.get())
    result_lable.grid(row=3, column=3)
    
    result_lable.config(text= w_entry.get())
    
    

# Calculate Button
b5 = Button(frame1, text="Calculate BMI", command=bmi)
b5.grid(row=4, column=3, columnspan=3)


frame1.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor="center")
frame1.mainloop()
```

[image: See the position of button]

**After pressing button, it pushed a littlie down from previous position**
[image: Now result is printed on window and button is moved from its previous position]

Comment: Set the row of `result_label` to 5.  Better create the label outside the function and update its text inside the function.

Comment: Yes. getting label out of function and updating its text using this line worked.  
 result_lable.config(text= w_entry.get())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the Label definition out of the function. Like this instead:

```
result_lable= Label(frame1)
result_lable.grid(row=3, column=3)

def bmi():
    result_lable.config(text= w_entry.get())
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you want, but if you want to reserve space for the BMI calculator result the way to do that is by setting a height parameter in the result label.
To do that, you will need to initialize the code at the start of software, so it would look like this:

```py
result_lable = Label(frame1, text=w_entry.get(), height=WHATEVER_YOU_WANT)
result_lable.grid(row=3, column=3)

def bmi():
    result_lable.config(text=w_entry.get())
```

That way there is going to be a set height to the label between the entries and the button, and it will not be pushed back when you calculate.